# Why Eclipse null pointer analysis failed to recognize assertion utilities?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction

I am asking the question more from a compiler theory point of view. Why null pointer analysis failed to consider the effect of `Assert.notNull()`?

[image: Code block show null reference access highlighted as error after Assert.notNull()]

The Assert method is from Spring and it is implemented as:

```
public static void notNull(Object object, String message) {
    if (object == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
    }
}

public static void notNull(Object object) {
    notNull(object, "[Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null");
}
```

(This becomes quite annoying because if I use this kind of assertion utilities, the first access to that variable after the assertion causes a warning, which prevents me from achieving warning-free code.)

If I inline the assertion routine completely, the access to `a` will not be marked as null pointer access (in this trivial case, it will become dead code). However, a static method cannot be overridden (not without bytecode fiddling), so what would be the rationale from a compiler designer's POV to not go inside the method call for null pointer analysis?

Is it just performance concern or is there something that prevents this from being done in general? Or to make it consistent with other compiler checks (dead code analysis did not consider that method either)?

Comment: The problem is Turing-complete in general, but even more limited solutions are almost certainly impractical.

Comment: Yes, no non-trivial code can be fully checked by machines due to the Halting Problem, but many can still be done statically. I could be wrong, but I believe if the analyzer inlined all (static) method calls, it should be able to do better with many trivial cases like mine, but it just stops at the method calls for some reason. I admit though after compilation, the target function can be easily replaced causing the validation to be invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is of course more a discussion than a question.

1. The jar's you compile with is not necessarily the jar you run with. Especially Assert would be a candidate to have a different implementation in production environment.
2. A null pointer error would be better than a dead code error (here).
3. The eclipse compiler continuously compiles in the background. So as intelligence is paid with speed loss, this check might be more for a tool like **findbugs**. (Think of all library calls, that via a runtime exception might disrupt the control flow.)

Answer (score 3):

> Why Eclipse null pointer analysis failed to recognize assertion utilities?

Because Eclipse null pointer analysis is only taking account of the statements of the method it is analysing ... not the semantics of the methods that are called.  (And I certainly wouldn't expect / want the Eclipse compiler's  analysis code to treat the `Spring` assertion methods as a special case.)

> This becomes quite annoying ...

Well turn off the null analysis then!!  (There should be an Eclipse compiler preference to do this.)

Or change your code so that the value is not always `null`.  Or delete the (dynamically) unreachable statement that dereferences the `null` reference.

To be quite honest, your example is so contrived that I cannot imagine anyone doing anything like that in real code.  There is no "fix" that doesn't change the meaning of your code.  I imagine this is not the case for your real code ...

---

When you think about it, the problem here is roughly equivalent to the problems of detecting uninitialized variables and unreachable statements in Java.  And Eclipse is adopting the same solution as Java / the JLS.

---

As for the idea that Eclipse *should* be using state of the art non-local analysis code ... I disagree.  It would make Eclipse's interactive compilation slow as treacle.

There are other reasons for not implementing this, including:

- the fact that the problem cannot be solved in the general case (the Halting problem),
- the fact that it is a technically difficult problem to solve in the cases where it is theoretically solvable,
- the fact that the extra code would need to be maintained, and
- the fact that the functionality would have **limited utility**.  (I mean seriously, do you *really* think it is worth spending many man-months to fix a minor irritation for a tiny subset of users that those users could solve for themselves in a few seconds ... by tweaking the compiler preferences?)

But if you feel that strongly about it, you are free to develop and test the analysis code and contribute it to the Eclipse project.

Comment: I can't accept two answers so I gave you an up vote. Joop's answer is more concise IMHO.